# Create a html select depending on which item was selected from the autocomplete input

Tags: javascript, php, json

I currently have a php page that searches the database and returns the results via JSON in an autocomplete input:

[image]

When I echo the response of this php file (for the example above), I get the following:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": [{
        "name": "Bananas, raw"
    }]
}
```

This fruit has five serving sizes stored in the database. What I need is to create its specific HTML SELECT after it was clicked on:

```
<select>
   <option>grams</option>
   <option>oz</option>
   <option>small size</option>
   <option>medium size</option>
   <option>large size</option>
</select>
```

**The serving sizes are all stored in the database and they are different for each food.**

Note: I could read in the same php file the needed options and put them in the JSON result, like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": [{
        "name": "Bananas, raw",
        "option1": "grams",
        "option2": "oz",
        "option3": "small size",
        "option4": "medium size",
        "option5": "large size"
    }]
}
```

So what I needed is to create the HTML select with the serving sizes of that selected fruit.

Can it be made dynamically on the same page, after the food was clicked on?
Thank you!

Comment: Please: [minimal effort](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+json+autocomplete+OR+typeahead+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Do you search something like: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete ?

Comment: @ChrisP , the autocomplete works fine. What I'm trying to do is to create a select based on the chosen input, if it is possible.

Comment: @mplungjan it's not the autocomplete problem here, it's creating that HTML select after it has been clicked on, depending on what was chosen.. I'm sorry if I didn't notice something obvious, I'm new to javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, here i changed click event for blur it feels a little bit more comfortable. Of course you can implement your own behavior. Please check results for some valid fruits name to try

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);

function handleBlur(event) {
    const options = getOptions(event.target.value);

    if (options) {
        populateSelect(options);
    }
}

function populateSelect(options) {
    const select = document.querySelector('select');
    const opts = options.map(option => `<option value=${option}>${option}</option>`).join('');

    select.innerHTML = opts;
}

function getOptions(key) {
    if (!key) {
        return;
    }

    const collection = [
        {
            "success": true,
            "results": [{
            "name": "Bananas, raw",
                "option1": "grams",
                "option2": "oz",
                "option3": "small size",
                "option4": "medium size",
                "option5": "large size"
            }]
        }, {
            "success": true,
            "results": [{
            "name": "Mango, raw",
                "option3": "small size",
                "option4": "medium size",
                "option5": "large size"
            }]
        }, {
            "success": true,
            "results": [{
            "name": "Pear, raw",
                "option1": "grams",
                "option2": "oz",
            }]
        },
    ];

    const options = collection.find(data => data.results[0].name.toLocaleLowerCase() === key.toLocaleLowerCase()).results[0];

    delete options.name

    return Object.values(options);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter">
<select name="option" id="option"></select>
```

I would advise you if it is in your hands to modify the structure of the json that you get when you click on the input. For example, if you take the name property of the results object and place it in the first level of the object, you can avoid manipulating the object as in the example. Doing this in results would only have the options of the selected fruit.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer! I think this might help me, but the code snippet is not working... I'm new to javascript, by the way, I only know php.

Comment: Its works, for example type `Mango, raw` and when input lost focus the select tag will be populated, you could also try with `Bananas, raw` and `Pear, raw`